# Kivy Images Not Showing Without Added Time

Tags: image, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy, raspbian

## Summary of this app:

- Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie and output to TV
- Python 3.4
- Kivy 1.9.1
- pet information is pulled through a SOAP request
- the information is parsed
- a kivy window is created and the pet information is displayed for a
  set interval before the next pet's information is displayed

## Issue:

- each pet has a single image (typically 20-60kB each) which many times is not being displayed
- initially I was using asynchronous loading to pull the image and display it direct from it's web address
- now I am downloading every image to a USB drive prior to starting the display sequence, but having the same issues
- the pre-loaded images open fine outside of the app
- when the images were pulled direct from the web, it took about a second for the image to display (or not display)
- now that the images are downloaded first, the images appear almost instantly (or not appear)
- the only way that I can guarantee that every image will display is to set the time interval between pets to 20 or more seconds (whether direct from the web or pulled from the USB stick)
- I tried using and not using asynchronous loading with images stored on the USB stick without success either way
- I've watched the folder on the USB stick and can see that the images load at a rate of about 1-3 images per second (total of about 110 images)
- I've tried adding a delay between the downloading/saving of each image with no luck
- the first 7 images always succeed, independent of whatever list of pets are loaded
- after the first 7 images, it is random with the success rate dependent on the time interval between pets being displayed
- I can't figure out why the added time is necessary for all images to show when the images are rather small and the ones that do show appear almost instantly

### Python

```
import kivy
import sys
import os
import time
import requests
kivy.require('1.9.1')
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

# from kivy.loader import Loader
# image = Loader.image('nophoto.png')
# Loader.error_image = 'nophoto.png'

# SET ADDRESS FOR SOAP
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://qag.petpoint.com/webservices/AdoptableSearch.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(url)

# DELETES PRELOADED IMAGES TO START WITH AN EMPTY USB FOLDER
for ea_file in os.listdir('/media/pi/PRELOAD'):
    thedress = '/media/pi/PRELOAD' + '/' + ea_file
    os.remove(thedress)

# PUSHES DYNAMIC INFO TO SCROLLER.KV
class TheBox(FloatLayout):
    def update(self, *args):
        global date_now, which_petL, which_petR, total_count, Lname, Lsex, Lbreed, Lage, Lphoto, Rname, Rsex, Rbreed, Rage, Rphoto
        quantity = len(ans_lists[0]) - 1

        ans_particular = feeder()
        Lname = ans_particular[0]
        Lsex = ans_particular[1]
        Lbreed = ans_particular[2]
        Lage = ans_particular[3]
        Lphoto = ans_particular[4]
        Rname = ans_particular[5]
        Rsex = ans_particular[6]
        Rbreed = ans_particular[7]
        Rage = ans_particular[8]
        Rphoto = ans_particular[9]

        self.ids.Start_Time.text = '%02d  %02d    %05d' % (date_now.day, date_now.hour, total_count)

        if (total_count % 2) == 0: 
            if which_petL < quantity:
                which_petL += 1
            else:
                which_petL = 0

            self.ids.PetL_name.text = str.upper(Lname)
            self.ids.PetL_sex.text = str(Lsex)
            self.ids.PetL_breed.text = str(Lbreed)
            self.ids.PetL_age.text = str(Lage)
            self.ids.PetL_photo.source = str(Lphoto)

        else:
            if which_petR < quantity:
                which_petR += 1
            else:
                which_petR = 0

            self.ids.PetR_name.text = str.upper(Rname)
            self.ids.PetR_sex.text = str(Rsex)
            self.ids.PetR_breed.text = str(Rbreed)
            self.ids.PetR_age.text = str(Rage)
            self.ids.PetR_photo.source = str(Rphoto)

# SOAP RESPONSE IS CONVERTED TO XML FORMAT
def reformat_soap():    
    result = client.service.adoptableSearch('0', 'A', 'All', 'not4u')

    ..

    root = ET.fromstring(closeit)
    return root

# ITERATES THE SOAP RESPONSE TO ASSIGN DATA TO LISTS
def pull_data(ans_root):
    lpetid = []
    lname = []
    lsex = []
    lbreed = []
    lage = []
    lphoto = []

    for child in ans_root.iter('pet_id'):

        ..

        iphoto = child.find('pet_photo').text

        # WEB ADDRESSES FOR IMAGES ARE USED TO CREATE LOCAL ADDRESSES
        local_name = iphoto.replace('http://sms.petpoint.com/sms/photos/615/','/media/pi/PRELOAD/')
        ghost_pet = local_name.replace('http://sms.petpoint.com/sms3/emails/images/','/media/pi/PRELOAD/')
        lphoto.extend([ghost_pet])

        # IMAGES ARE DOWNLOADED FROM THE WEB AND SAVED LOCALLY
        photo_cache = open(ghost_pet, 'wb')
        photo_cache.write(requests.get(iphoto).content)
#       time.sleep(2)
        photo_cache.close()

    return(lname, lsex, lbreed, lage, lphoto)

# ASSEMBLES PET DATA PRIOR TO PUSH
def feeder():
    global which_petL, which_petR, cname, csex, cbreed, cage, cphoto
    pname = cname[which_petL]
    psex = csex[which_petL]
    pbreed = cbreed[which_petL]
    page = cage[which_petL]
    pphoto = cphoto[which_petL]
    qname = cname[which_petR]
    qsex = csex[which_petR]
    qbreed = cbreed[which_petR]
    qage = cage[which_petR]
    qphoto = cphoto[which_petR]    
    return(pname, psex, pbreed, page, pphoto, qname, qsex, qbreed, qage, qphoto) 

ans_root = reformat_soap()
ans_lists = pull_data(ans_root)
which_petR = int(len(ans_lists[0]) / 2)

cname = ans_lists[0]
csex = ans_lists[1]
cbreed = ans_lists[2]
cage = ans_lists[3]
cphoto = ans_lists[4]

# DEFINES THE KIVY APP, INTERVAL BETWEEN PET DISPLAYS, AND TIES TO SCROLLER.KV
class ScrollerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('Scroller.kv')
        x = TheBox()
        x.update()
        Clock.schedule_interval(x.update, 10)
        return(x)

# KIVY WINDOW CREATION
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollerApp().run()
```

### Kivy Language

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}
            Image:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: (0, 0, 0)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                id: PetL_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
            Label:
                ..
            Label:
                ..
            Label:
                ..
            Label:
                ..
        FloatLayout:
            ..
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .79}
            Image:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: (0, 0, 0)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                id: PetR_photo
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source:
            Label:
                ..
            Label:
                ..
            Label:
                ..
            Label:
                ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Not positive on this on this correlation, but it seems to make sense. I increased the GPU memory for the Raspberry Pi from 64 to 128MB and now the application is able to successfully display the images with a much smaller interval between image changes.